# Rails: Simple unit test not executing in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to learn testing but my unit test isn't working. So I have a user model (and other models as well, but haven't started testing them yet):

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :gender, :name

  has_many :sent_messages, :class => "Messages", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_messages, :class => "Messages", :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'

  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :language

  before_save { |user| if user.new_record? then create_remember_token end }


    private

        def create_remember_token
            self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        end

end
```

and a test/unit/users_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "user is created" do
    user = User.create!(:name => "Edmund")
    assert_equal user, User.first
  end
end
```

but when I run `rake test:units` I get:

```
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:langexchange edmundmai$ rake test:units
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "languages_id_seq" for serial column "languages.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "languages_pkey" for table "languages"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "locations_id_seq" for serial column "locations.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "locations_pkey" for table "locations"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "messages_id_seq" for serial column "messages.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "messages_pkey" for table "messages"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"
/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:51:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: class (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:50:in `each_key'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:50:in `assert_valid_keys'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:33:in `validate_options'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:24:in `build'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:139:in `build'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb:14:in `build'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:12:in `build'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1428:in `belongs_to'
    from /Users/edmundmai/Desktop/Class/Ruby/langexchange/app/models/messages.rb:4:in `<class:Messages>'
    from /Users/edmundmai/Desktop/Class/Ruby/langexchange/app/models/messages.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/edmundmai/Desktop/Class/Ruby/langexchange/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/edmundmai/Desktop/Class/Ruby/langexchange/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/edmundmai/Desktop/Class/Ruby/langexchange/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/edmundmai/Desktop/Class/Ruby/langexchange/test/unit/helpers/home_helper_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/edmundmai/Desktop/Class/Ruby/langexchange/test/unit/helpers/home_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib" "/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]
Tasks: TOP => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

how is this possible?? Can someone help? I haven't written any other tests so I don't know how it's going berserk

UPDATE
Messages model:

```
class Messages < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :read

  belongs_to :sender, :class => "User", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class => "User", :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
end
```

Comment: Did you run `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: hey ian. nope i have never seen that. is that a standard command that i have to run before running tests?

Comment: running that just gives me the `NOTICE:`s with the create tables that you see above. After that I ran `rake test:units` again and nothing changed. the error is still the same

Comment: Yeah `rake db:test:prepare` sets your test database up. You need to run it everytime you DB schema changes(ie. running a migration). You likely have an error somewhere in your code. (as Veraticus mentions) if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your Users model you use

```
has_many :sent_messages, :class => "Messages", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
has_many :received_messages, :class => "Messages", :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
```

you should be using:

```
has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Messages", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Messages", :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
```

(switched `:class` to `:class_name`)

---

In associations there is no such thing as the `:class` option. What you want is the `:class_name` option. (You will have to change ever model that uses this.)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference

Comment: thanks! fixing both the `User` and `Message` models by replacing `:class` to `:class_name` fixed it. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From that stack trace, you appear to have an error in your `Messages` model. If you correct that error, this should run correctly.

Comment: hey vera, can you tell me which line helped you figure out it was `messages`?

Comment: i looked through (and pasted in the question) my messages model... I don't see anything wrong with it...

Comment: `from /Users/edmundmai/Desktop/Class/Ruby/langexchange/app/models/messages.rb:4:in `<class:Messages>'` Looks like this is the error: Unknown key: class (ArgumentError)